# Pressing Text Not Triggering Canvas Tagbind

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

This is a Tkinter Canvas Python program. The code in this stage of development is supposed to basically let you press a button (and undo if you want by pressing again), then a button from the other side (not the same side), and it will run a function to print the buttons you pressed if you do so. That part is working perfectly fine. I used a canvas tagbind to trigger the functions and set the tags of the button (which is a canvas rectangle so I can set the exact size) and the text to the same. However, it still won't activate when pressing the text. Anyone know why? Last time I posted here, it got taken down for not having a repeatable example, so I'll paste the entire code this time:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=600, height=800)
c.pack()
Button1 = c.create_rectangle(100, 100, 300, 300, fill='white', tag='1')
Button2 = c.create_rectangle(300, 100, 500, 300, fill='white', tag='2')
Button3 = c.create_rectangle(100, 500, 300, 700, fill='white', tag='3')
Button4 = c.create_rectangle(300, 500, 500, 700, fill='white', tag='4')
Text1 = c.create_text(200, 200, font=('Helvetica', 20), text='1', tag='1')
Text2 = c.create_text(400, 200, font=('Helvetica', 20), text='1', tag='2')
Text3 = c.create_text(200, 600, font=('Helvetica', 20), text='1', tag='3')
Text4 = c.create_text(400, 600, font=('Helvetica', 20), text='1', tag='4')
pressed = 0
def game(starting, target):
    print(starting, target)
def onePressed(event):
    global pressed
    c.itemconfig(Button1, fill='green')
    if pressed == 0:
        pressed = 1
    elif pressed == 1:
        c.itemconfig(Button1, fill='white')
        pressed = 0
    elif pressed == 2:
        c.itemconfig(Button1, fill='white')
    elif pressed == (3 or 4):
        game(pressed, 1)
def twoPressed(event):
    global pressed
    c.itemconfig(Button2, fill='green')
    if pressed == 0:
        pressed = 2
    elif pressed == 1:
        c.itemconfig(Button2, fill='white')
    elif pressed == 2:
        c.itemconfig(Button2, fill='white')
        pressed = 0
    elif pressed == (3 or 4):
        game(pressed, 2)
def threePressed(event):
    global pressed
    c.itemconfig(Button3, fill='green')
    if pressed == 0:
        pressed = 3
    elif pressed == (1 or 2):
        game(pressed, 3)
    elif pressed == 3:
        c.itemconfig(Button3, fill='white')
        pressed = 0
    elif pressed == 4:
        c.itemconfig(Button3, fill='white')
def fourPressed(event):
    global pressed
    c.itemconfig(Button4, fill='green')
    if pressed == 0:
        pressed = 4
    elif pressed == (1 or 2):
        game(pressed, 4)
    elif pressed == 3:
        c.itemconfig(Button4, fill='white')
    elif pressed == 4:
        c.itemconfig(Button4, fill='white')
        pressed = 0
c.tag_bind('1', '<ButtonPress-1>', onePressed)
c.tag_bind('2', '<ButtonPress-1>', twoPressed)
c.tag_bind('3', '<ButtonPress-1>', threePressed)
c.tag_bind('4', '<ButtonPress-1>', fourPressed)
```

By the way, all the functions in the middle shouldn't matter, since those are just the commands run with the tagbind, and to make the program executable. I think I remember having a problem similar to this in the past, and I don't remember solving it.

Comment: _"By the way, all the functions in the middle shouldn't matter"_ - if that's the case, please remove them from the code. The code should be as small as possible. See [mcve] for recommendations on how to write the example code.

Comment: Don't use tags '1', '2', '3' and '4' and they will be treated as integers and these integers will refer to the four rectangles only.  Use something like 't1', 't2', 't3' and 't4' instead.

Comment: @BryanOakley so do you mean I should edit the code to still be runnable, just without those functions?

Comment: You have total of 4 boxes. You will have to do 16(4*4) combinations to get boxes working.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that if you put a bind on a rectangle, and there is text on the rectangle, and you click the text instead of the rectangle, you expect the binding on the rectangle to fire when it doesn't. Is that a correct re-phrasing of the question?

Comment: @BryanOakley the question was solved by acw1668 but I can't credit it as the answer because it's a comment. Also, yes, that is the problem